# Apache redirection based on referrer in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, virtual-host

**How can I configure Apache httpd on a CentOS 7 server so that requests for any path under `home.mydomain.com` are only served if the referrer for the request was from a path under `mydomain.com`?**  And so that requests from referrers other than `mydomain.com` are redirected to `mydomain.com/login`?

Here are the `VirtualHost` definitions for `mydomain.com` and for `host.mydomain.com`:

```
<VirtualHost www.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_com_requests.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost home.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerName home.mydomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

> < VirtualHost home.mydomain.com:80>
>
> ServerName home.mydomain.com
>
> order Allow,Deny
>
> Allow from 127.0.0.1/8
>
> Allow from mydomain.com
>
> < /VirtualHost>

For more information See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html